# What is the error in this code of react? When i call the function in part 1 it doesnt work but part 2 works

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-forms

This is my code. when i use function in part 1 it shows nothing on console. but when i use function in part 2 it shows 'Hello'. but i cant see any differences. What am i doing wrong in part 1?

```
    handleChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.id]:e.target.value
        })
    }
    // part 1
    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.prevendDefault()
        console.log(this.state)
        console.log("hello")
    }
    // part 2
    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(this.state)
        console.log('hello')
      }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="form-group container w-50">
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <label htmlFor="">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" id="email"className="form-control" onChange={this.handleChange}  />

                    <label htmlFor="">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" id="password" className="form-control" onChange={this.handleChange}/>

                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" >Submit</button>
                </form>


            </div>
        );
    }
```

Comment: There is a typo in part 1, `e.prevendDefault()` should be `e.preventDefault()`. You should see an error in the console `function prevendDefault does not exist on e`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a spelling mistake

```
   handleSubmit = (e) => {
       e.prevendDefault()
       console.log(this.state)
       console.log("hello")
   }
```

it's `preventDefault()` but you had `prevendDefault`.

I would suggest using an IDE or editor with `IntelliSense` or autocomplete feature to prevent these kinds of mistakes in the future.

Comment: thank you so much. i am using VS code. could you please suggest me some extension for React, Firebase.

Comment: If you are using VS Code it's probably because you didn't tab complete it then. Generally speaking, it shows up as this is a standard method on the event object. As for react plugin, I would just go to the plugin tab and do a search for react and firebase, normally the ones with the highest hits and most download is good as lots of people are using it but always read what it does. @akshay2739